# What are some reasons that application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method could get skipped?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad

My iPad app was working fine until I opened up IB and started editing the interface.  Now, my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions isn't getting called.  I understand it's an optional function and it gets skipped if it doesn't exist, but in my case it does.  What are some reasons that application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method could get skipped?

I should note that I'm building with the iPhone OS 3.2 SDK.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE:** I fixed it, please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that class has been set as the application delegate of the app?

[image]
<sub>(source: [xanga.com](https://x82.xanga.com/571f632b65032267509515/w213386740.png))</sub>

And also make sure the "File's Owner"'s `delegate` has been linked to "App Delegate".

[image]
<sub>(source: [xanga.com](https://x1f.xanga.com/fd2e122773c34267509658/w213386867.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks again, Kenny, you've been a huge help all day! I really appreciate it. I found the "File Owner's" delegate wasn't linked to the "App Delegate", but after linking it and saving, the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method is still being skipped for some reason.  I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

Well it turns out, for an unknown reason, I had a "view" view object as a child of my RootViewController in IB that didn't serve any purpose except to hold my a TableView view object and a DatePicker view object.  I thought it was harmless, but when I removed it in IB and programmatically added the TableView object and and DatePicker object, suddenly this problem went away.  If anyone has any ideas why this is, I'd would love to understand it.

Thanks, everyone!